# TSQL update NULLs only when between the same values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, group-by, updates

I have a table where I need to fill in the NULLs with data.  However, I only want to replace the NULL if the before and after values are the same.

```
G  ID   Val    NewValue
a   1   N       N
a   2   N       N
a   3   NULL    NULL   -- notice this is the last value of group 'a' so keep NULL and if NULL was the first of the group, keep NULL as well

b   4   P       P
b   5   N       N
b   6   NULL    N     -- N before and N after so the new value ='N'
b   7   N       N

c   8   N       N
c   9   N       N
c   10  NULL    NULL  -- N before but P after so keep NULL
c   11  P       P
c   12  N       N
c   13  N       N
c   14  N       N

d   15  P       P
d   16  NULL    P    --  P before and P after (the series) so make 'P'
d   17  NULL    P    --  P before and P after (the series) so make 'P'
d   18  P       P
d   19  N       N
```

So what I have a solution for the easy part.  The query below gives:

- Correct results for IDs = 6, 16, and 17
- Incorrect results for IDs = 3 and 10

So my question is how to do the rest?

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    G varchar(1),
    ID INT,
    Val varchar(2)
    )
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('a',1,'N'),('a',2,'N'),('a',3, NULL),
('b',4,'P'),('b',5,'N'),('b',6, NULL),('b',7,'N'),
('c',8, 'N'),('c',9, 'N'),('c',10,NULL),('c',11,'P'),('c',12,'N'),('c',13,'N'),('c',14,'N'),
('d',15, 'P'),('d',16, NULL),('d',17,NULL),('d',18,'P'),('d',19,'N')
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN Val IS NULL 
     THEN (SELECT TOP 1 Val FROM @Table WHERE ID<T.ID AND G=T.G AND Val IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC) 
     ELSE Val END AS NewVal
FROM @Table T

ORDER BY G, ID
```

Comment: Use LAG/LEAD and you should be able to do this

Comment: As @dfundako says, a simple use of LAG/LEAD with partitioning on the 'G' column on would be good, except for the final case in the example, where there multiple NULLs in sequence...

Comment: Did not know about LAG/LEAD very interesting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing when you solve problems is to understand the approach in plain English. Here, for example, all you need is to find two closest non-NULL values, the most preceding and the least subsequent. When they exist and are equal, use their value.

Here is a translation of this approach into SQL:

```
select t.*, isnull(t.Val, case when pr.Val = nr.Val then pr.Val end) as [NewVal]
from @table t
    outer apply (
        select top (1) tp.Val from @table tp
        where tp.G = t.G and tp.Val is not null and tp.Id < t.Id
        order by tp.Id desc
    ) pr
    outer apply (
        select top (1) tn.Val from @table tn
        where tn.G = t.G and tn.Val is not null and tn.Id > t.Id
        order by tn.Id
    ) nr
order by t.g, t.Id;
```

Comment: Have not used APPLY before either!  Two new SQL functions (for me) in one question.  You guys are awesome.  Is there anyway to predict if this query will bog down with lots of data in the table?  The table I want to run it on is ~150K rows.

Comment: 150K is peanuts, but the query would definitely benefit from proper indices. Say, clustered / PK on `(G, Id)` and a nonclustered on `Val`. Besides, if I understand correctly, you need to update only some rows, not all.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you what you need minus the last one which you'd need to explain the logic and how you'd handle that.

```
SELECT
    t.G,
    t.ID,
    val,
    case 
        when val is null and 
             lag(val) over (partition by G order by ID) = lead(val) over (partition by G  order by ID) then lag(val) over (partition by G order by ID) 
        else val 
    end as NewValue
FROM @Table T
```